# How to programmatically load an XLL file into Excel?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, excel, office-interop

How to programmatically load an XLL file into Excel when it is linked to other DLLs.
Using c# winforms application + Excel Automation I’m creating Excel Application object. Then I’m using:

```
bool bXllLoadSuccess = _excelApp.RegisterXLL(_pathXll);
```

It is OK when XLL is self-contained. The problem occurs when it depends on other DLLs. Even when I put them into the same folder Excel doesn’t want to pick them up.
I tried to do following before loading the XLL but it doesn’t help:

```
_excelApp.DefaultFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(_pathXll);
```

I have tried this one as well:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_pathXll));
```

Dependency walker shows no issues – all required files are in the same folder with the XLL.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPD:** I tried copying all requried dlls into a folder and then added it's path to PATH variable. Didn't help :)

**UPD2:** I tried to change current directory for both c# app and Excel application object at the same time. Didn't help :(

Comment: Does it work when you File -> Open the .xll?
Does it work from VBA using Application.RegisterXLL?

Comment: Yep... It does when I add it by hands. Haven't tried with VBA though... let me try...

Comment: Is the xll perhaps built with managed code (Excel-DNA / ManagedXLL / Add-In Express or similar)? If so, probably a .NET CAS issue when calling from VSTO. Some posts here: http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/search?q=vsto+registerxll&start=0&scoring=d&